# Strange behaviour of DateTime.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

We have a large application that (unfortunately) use DateTime.Parse(text) a lot.  Replacing DateTime.Parse with something better is not an option right now.

Recently I upgraded windows (to windows 10) and started to have issues. According to the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx the method should use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as default formatprovider. This does not appear to be the case on my pc, unless I'm missing something obvious.

The following code calls a function two times, first without changing any culture settings, then with norwegian culture set on both the culture and ui-culture.
For some reason it is able to parse a text given in en-US format (M/d/yyyy) in both cases, but it is unable to parse a date in the format expected by CultureInfo.

What is going on here? I hope I'm missing something obvious..

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var norwegianCulture = new CultureInfo("nb-NO");

        Console.WriteLine("First");
        ParseDates();

        Console.WriteLine("\nSecond");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = norwegianCulture;
        ParseDates();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void ParseDates()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CultureInfo.CurrentCulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}");
        Console.WriteLine($"CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture: {CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture} - CurrentCulture - {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture} - CurrentUICulture - {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern}");
        var shortDateString = new DateTime(2015, 9, 5).ToShortDateString();
        WriteParsedDate(shortDateString);
        WriteParsedDate("1/2/2015");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void WriteParsedDate(string shortDateString)
    {
        try
        {
            var d = DateTime.Parse(shortDateString, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            Console.WriteLine($"The text {shortDateString} parsed to Year: {d.Year}, Month: {d.Month}, Day: {d.Day}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The text {shortDateString} could not be parsed.");
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Writes this to the console:

```
First
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture: nb-NO
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture: en-US
nb-NO - CurrentCulture - dd.MM.yyyy
en-US - CurrentUICulture - M/d/yyyy
The text 05.09.2015 could not be parsed.
Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
The text 1/2/2015 parsed to Year: 2015, Month: 2, Day: 1


Second
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture: nb-NO
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture: nb-NO
nb-NO - CurrentCulture - dd.MM.yyyy
nb-NO - CurrentUICulture - dd.MM.yyyy
The text 05.09.2015 could not be parsed.
Error: Strengen ble ikke gjenkjent som en gyldig DateTime.
The text 1/2/2015 parsed to Year: 2015, Month: 2, Day: 1
```

---

### PARTIAL WORKAROUND

As shf301 writes, this is due to a bug in Windows 10.

I managed to get it to work by changing the time seperator from "." to ":" - As in older versions of Windows. I guess it's working with that change since we are only using the users settings, and not loading/specifying them manually.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be using en-US either, because if it was then the month should 1 and the day 2, but you are getting the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an open bug listed [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1621722).  It [appears](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/3f5z5w/datetime_parsing_fails_in_windows_10/) that date parsing is failing for any locale that has the same separator's for date and time.

```
Estonian (Estonia)
Finnish (Finland)
Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)
Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard and Jan Mayen)
Serbian (Cyrillic, Kosovo)
Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)
Serbian (Latin, Serbia)
Serbian (Latin, Kosovo)
```

Your example never parses nor format's the date using US settings.  First of all `DateTime.Parse` without an `IFormatProvider` uses `CurrentCulture` and not `CurrentUICulture` and second you explicitly pass `CurrentCulture` into `DateTime.Parse`.   That's why the output in both cases is exactly the same.

Had `"1/2/2015"` been parsed using `en-US` rules, it would have output:

```
The text 1/2/2015 parsed to Year: 2015, Month: 1, Day: 2
```

`DateTime.Parse` is just being clever and assuming that you used a `/` as a date separator instead of a `.` and parsing the date as `d/M/yyyy`.

Until this is fixed you will unfortunately have to changed your calls to `DateTime.Parse`.  Or switch to .Net 3.5 or earlier which is not affected.

Comment: Thank you! I realy hope this gets fixed soon, since this now prevents all of our other developers from upgrading windows.

Comment: According to the following post the fix will be out in the September Windows 10 update:  http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2015/08/windows-10-breaks-net-date-parsing-in-certain-locales/

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3081455 (Yesterdays update) did NOT fix this for me.